# Get-ChildItem return access denied error when run as "SYSTEM"

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to create a script to get content of a folder across the network. I noticed that Get-Childitem throw "Access Denied" error on every other IP addresses in the list.

For example i listed the IP like this:

- IP1
- IP2
- IP3
- IP4

Get-ChildItem worked for IP1 and IP3 but return access denied error for IP2 and IP4. This only happens if I run the script on a console that run as SYSTEM.
**Edit:** The remote tool I create this script for can only run console as system

Can someone tell me if there's anything in the code that might cause this issue?

```
#Set Variables
$pw = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter password"
$usrname = 'username'
$folderpath = 'C$\Folder\Subfolder1\Subfolder'

#Loop
foreach ($ipaddress in Get-Content -Path .\DeviceIPList.txt) {
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("$ipaddress\$usrname",$pw)
    Try {
        if ($(Test-Path drv:) -eq 'True') {
            Remove-PSDrive "drv"
        } else { 
            New-PSDrive -Name "drv" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$ipaddress\C$" -Credential $credential -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        } 
        $vhdfile = Get-ChildItem -path "\\$ipaddress\$folderpath" -ErrorAction Stop    
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$ipaddress,Found $vhdfile in $($folderpath.Replace('$',':'))"
        Write-Output "$ipaddress,Found $vhdfile in $($folderpath.Replace('$',':'))" | Out-File -Append .\Report.txt
        }
    Catch [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception] {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "$ipaddress,$_"
        Write-Output "$ipaddress,$_" | Out-File -Append .\Report.txt
        }
    Catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$ipaddress,$_"
        Write-Output "$ipaddress,$_" | Out-File -Append .\Report.txt
        }
    Finally {
        $error.Clear()
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        net use \\$ipaddress\$folderpath /d 2>&1>$null
        }
}
```

Comment: The system account is for the local system, usually you can't use the system account to connect to remote machines.

Comment: I apologize, I've updated the post for clarification. The tool i use can only run consoles as system unfortunately. Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `drv:` exists, your `if` statement here will remove it, **but** won't create a new drive. Try moving `New-PSDrive` outside the `Else`:

```
if ($(Test-Path drv:) -eq 'True') {
  Remove-PSDrive "drv"
} 
New-PSDrive -Name "drv" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$ipaddress\C$" -Credential $credential -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
```

This is an issue because you're using the whole `\\$ip\c$\` unc in `Get-ChildItem`. If the `drv:` got removed, then you're asking `Get-ChildItem` to connect as the current user instead, which isn't going to work as `system`. It's also probably the reason you can connect every *other* time.

Using `drv:` should show you if this is the issue by throwing a "`drv:` doesn't exist" kind of error:

```
$folderpath = 'Folder\Subfolder1\Subfolder'
$vhdfile = Get-ChildItem -path "drv:\$folderpath" -ErrorAction Stop
```

It may be that SYSTEM is not able to use `net use /d` to remove the PSDrive - it may be throwing errors, but you've nulled its output. Try using `Remove-PSDrive` again here instead:

```
Finally {
  $error.Clear()
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
  Remove-PSDrive "drv"
}
```

Running as system is fine since you're giving different credentials to `New-PSDrive`.

Comment: That worked! I moved new-psdrive out of else and change the path for child-item as you suggested.